# EllipseCurve intersect EllipseCurve

Tags: three.js, intersection, raycasting, ellipse

Нelo! I need to find the intersection point of two ellipses in webgl (three js). Not found in documentation as can be to apply Raycaster.

I draw ellipse as:

```
    var curve = new THREE.EllipseCurve(
      x, // X
      y,  // Y
      xRadius,  // xRadius
      yRadius,  // yRadius
      0, // aStartAngle
      Math.PI*2,  // aEndAngle
      false,            // aClockwise
      0                 // aRotation
    );

    var points = curve.getPoints( 100 );
    var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( points );
    var item = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
    scene.add( item = );
```

Comment: There is no such functionality out-of-box. You have to implement it yourself. 

And how do you plan to use Raycaster in this case?

Comment: I used the ray to find the intersection of the lines. Expected to apply for curves.

Comment: It's better to get ellipses as sets of segments and find find intersections of the segments.